# How to convert floating point numbers in R

Tags: r, type-conversion

I have been trying to convert the following to decimal floating point numbers with no luck.

```
x <- c("0,989" "0,990" "0,991" "0,990" "0,989" "0,989" "0,990" "0,990" "0,989")
```

These are characters in my data frame but `as.numeric(as.character(x))` doesn't help. It generates bunch of NAs.

I would appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: How did you get this data into R? Most of the importing functions like `read.table` allow you to specify the decimal separator so they are imported as numbers to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the commas in the string.  Replace the commas using `gsub` like so:

```
new <- gsub(",", ".", x)
```

Then you can convert to numeric

```
result <- as.numeric(new)
```